# Not able to Upload nested multipart form-data in swift

Tags: django, swift, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data, alamofire

Hello everyone I have a problem with uploading nested multipart form-data in swift I tried to use alamofire but its not doing what i want it to do:(.
My Server is running the Django Rest Framework and just uploading an Image and parameters works just fine the problem is to upload user data with nested image and additional user data.
So think im doing something wrong with the syntax of the nested form-data heres my function that is working and is creating a user but is the server is not able to save the Image

```
func createUserWithImage(userName username: String, email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, completion: UserHandler = nil) {
    var user: User? = nil
    defer { completion?(user) }

    let testField: String = "testoftestfield"
    let status: String = "test of status"
    let parameters = [
        "username": username,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
    ]

    let image = UIImage(named: "ali.jpg")

    Alamofire.upload(.POST, Endpoint.RegisterUser.url, multipartFormData: {
        multipartFormData in

        if let _image = image {
            print("test1")
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image, 0.5) {
                print("test2")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "profile[profileImage]", fileName: "profileImage.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
        }

        }, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)

                    let json = JSON(upload)

                    print("The Upload is: " + json.description)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })

}
```

So does anyone has a clue how to send nested multipart form-data?:)

Answer (score 1):

func uploadImageWithFormedData() -> () {

```
  /* My URL:http://162.74.44.11/ImageApp/index.php/api/user/set_pic;

     Input Parameter :
   InputDict:
    {
        "user_id" = "1",
        "avtar" = "default",
        "picture" = "image.png"
    }
```

*/

```
    let BoundaryConstant  = "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let FileParamConstant = "picture"

    let requestURL:URL = URL(string: "http://162.74.44.11/ImageApp/index.php/api/user/set_pic")! as URL

    var request : URLRequest = URLRequest (url: requestURL, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpShouldHandleCookies = false;
    let  contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(BoundaryConstant)"
    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.

```
    var _params = [String:String]()

    _params.updateValue(user_id, forKey: "user_id")
    _params.updateValue("default", forKey: "avtar")

    var body:Data = Data()
    for (key,value) in _params
    {
        body.append("--\(BoundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)


    }

    let imageData:Data? = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "girl_greendotted_cloth")!)

    if imageData != nil {
        body.append("--\(BoundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(FileParamConstant)\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        body.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        body.append(imageData!)

        body.append("\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }

    body.append("--\(BoundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    request.httpBody = body

    request.setValue("\(body.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let  task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) in


        if (data != nil)
        {
            do{
                let dict =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves)
                print(dict);
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }

    }
    )

    task.resume()


     }
```